# Using a batch file or excel to find numbers beforea certain text inside a text file

Tags: excel, batch-file

Thank you for the responses. Anyway i have edited my question.You guys did a great help, almost getting to the result i want.However that certain text is case sensitive and there will be random numbers behind. Below is the edited version.

Wish to create a batch file to find numbers before a certain text inside a text file.
Can use excel as alternative as long as the value are being grabbed

Example: Below is the content of the testing.txt file.

```
2021 12345 hello-222 qwerty
2022 23456 hello-321 asdfg
2033 34567 hello-8473 zxcvb
```

Expected results

```
12345
23456
34567
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in (yourfilename) do echo %%a
```

should extract that data. See `for /?` from the prompt for documentation.

This assumes the default separator of <kbd>Space</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

"Beside" is a confusing term: numbers *before* or *after* the certain text? How the "certain text" is given? Case sensitive or not?

The Batch file below find *tokens* placed *before* the certain text inside a text file, case sensitive.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set certainText=hello-world
for /F "delims=" %%a in (testing.txt) do (
   set "previous="
   for %%b in (%%a) do (
      if "%%b" equ "%certainText%" echo !previous!
      set "previous=%%b"
   )
)
```

Comment: the certain text is case sensitive. something like HELLO-123, HELLO-476,HELLO-8674.I will still get the value before that.THanks guys

Comment: this solution IS case sensitive. If you want it case insensitive, just use the `if` with the `/i` parameter.